# load local model using `WhisperForConditionalGeneration` class

Tags: openai-whisper

i am trying to load a locally downloaded model using `WhisperForConditionalGeneration` class. I can load using first two approaches:

model1 is a `WhisperModel` wrapped in `WhisperForConditionalGeneration`

model2 is a `Whisper` model with different param names.

I am trying to load a local tiny.pt model that would be wrapped in `WhisperForConditionalGeneration` class.

model3 approach fails.

```
model1 = WhisperForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("openai/whisper-tiny")
model2 = whisper.load_model("./models/tiny.pt")
model3 = WhisperForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("./models/tiny.pt")
```

> OSError: Incorrect path_or_model_id:  Please provide either the path to a local folder or the repo_id of a model on the Hub.